# Virtual hosts on Mac OS X Lion not obeying DocumentRoot

Tags: osx-lion, apache-http-server

I uncommented the following line in httpd.conf file.

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And then added the following code in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 15ive.com
  ServerAlias *.15ive.com
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/15five/web"
  <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/15five/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
  SetEnv DEV 1
  SetEnv BASEDOMAIN 15ive.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/images|/scripts|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico|/pma15$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

And now when I open 15ive.com in my browser, I am actually seeing the document root of localhost instead of what I specified in the virtual hosts file. It seems like apache is not picking it up. Any idea where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Open your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file, and go to the *Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf* line.

Look for:

```
<IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON> ... </IfDefine>
```

which wraps around a few includes in that area, **and delete those lines**. If you use the GUI for apache on OSX, you could set "WEBSHARING_ON", but like me you're prob using httpd -k start.

Answer (score 1):

Did you uncomment

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

in your Apache httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

I would move the Directory directive first out and than above the VirtualHost directive.

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/15five/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 15ive.com
  ServerAlias *.15ive.com
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/15five/web"
  SetEnv DEV 1
  SetEnv BASEDOMAIN 15ive.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/images|/scripts|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico|/pma15$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```